# strtoull based on the input string

Tags: c, string

I have a tool called romflasher that takes two string commandline parameters `--s-addr0` 
and `--e-addr0`

```
romflasher --s-addr0 0x1c40000 --e-addr0 0x1e40000
```

Inside my program romflasher.c

```
 char s_addr_0[256];
 char e_addr_0[256];

 uint32_t start_addr = strtoull(s_addr_0,(char**)NULL,16);
 uint32_t end_addr   = strtoull(e_addr_0,(char**)NULL,16);
```

This works fine as long as the user specifies the address as hexadecimal.I want to give the user the option to specify it in both decimal as well as hexadecimal.Is there a function that will do the appropriate string conversion based on the presence of `'0x'` prefix to the correct base?

Comment: You should not typecast `NULL`, it's supposed to be a generic pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass 0 as the `base` argument, `strtoull` recognizes `0x` and `0` prefix to indicate hex and octal, respectively, and defaults to decimal otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write a wrapper function to strtoull (mystrtoull) and detect 0x in the strings and accordingly pass base parameter to strtoull?

Comment: I could do that.just wanted to know if there are existing methods to solve this issue.